# Migrated away question list shows all questions as having no answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration, 10k-tools

There's a list of [recently migrated questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/away) that are available as part of the 10k tools. The list shows the usual vote/answer/views count. Unfortunately, since migrated *away* questions are automatically deleted, the answers count shows zero for all questions on the list, making it useless. Either show the proper answer count, or remove the column as it is a waste of space.

[image]

(With exception of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494743/tidying-up-net-objects?noredirect=1), seen at the bottom of the image, which strangely was *not* deleted automatically. Could this be another bug?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intentional, we'd rather have the question list here like *almost every other question list on the site* than be jarring on a switch, even between "here" and "away" on that screen.  Also, the answers *can* be undeleted (though rare), it won'tn *always* be 0, as you see in your screenshot.

Comment: But shouldn't the list show the answer count to actually be useful? "Like any other list" doesn't make a lot of sense as I do not believe there is a list of deleted question of this kind displayed to 10/20k users anywhere else on the site. And that question in the screenshot might be a bug, since I don't see it being deleted in the first place in the revision history: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8494743/revisions

Comment: @YiJiang's - There are some title-only lists out there, but the format of vote, answer, views is used on every /questions page, /unanswered, everywhere in the profile, etc...showing it *slightly* different **only here** isn't useful, it does more harm than good and breaks the rule of least surprise.  Also keep in mind that migrations in the other direction *do* have answers, so switching the UI between subtabs for this column also isn't something we want, it's jarring and unnecessary.

Comment: Well, there's the option of actually show the answer count instead of all zeros. 10k users can see those deleted answers anyway so I don't think it's that big a deal if they can see it on this page too

Comment: @YiJiang's - Underneath, it's not a very small deal, keep in mind that's a normalized number that's surfaced on the view, not something we calculate every time...and we can't determine what was deleted as part of the migration and what was deleted for another reason in an efficient way.  You can't even join +/- on migration date because a question can bounce.

Comment: Mmmhmm, fair enough